# How to track the game battle result game analytics event properly

Tags: firebase, analytics, firebase-analytics

I would like to track the equipment and skills the players use in the pvp battle. So I will know which equipment and skill the player use most and the win rate of them.
However, we have many equipment and abilities per player. So I guess the event will look like this:
Event name: match_end
Parameters: game_mode, ability1, ability2, ability3, ability4, equipment1, equipment2, equipment3, equipment4, equipment5, equipment6, match_result, match_duration, gold_earn, character_use, score_earn

- Is this a correct approach? If the player has many equipment (up to 10) and ability (up to 8 ), we may reach the limit of 25 parameters per event (Firebase, Unity is only 10).
- Or should I use the following approach:

> **Event name:** match_end Parameters: game_mode, match result,
>   match_duration, score_earn, gold_earn
>
> **Event name:** ability_use_in_pvp_match Parameters: game_mode, ability1,
>   ability2, ability 3, etc.
>
> **Event name:** equipment_use_in_pvp_match Parameters: game_mode,
>   equipment1, equipment2, etc.

- There is another option is to use JSON string as the parameter and then use the queries to query from raw data. But this is way complicated and I cannot use the beautiful dasboard.

Comment: Not an expert in firebase, but for what you want to track, do you want to track how many times an ability is used in each battle? Would the max number of equipment always be the same? How many total times would any ability be used in a battle? I am thinking if you want to track each battle as one event or each ability used as one event.

Comment: Yes. How many times the ability/equipment was used. Max number is always the same.

Comment: Perhaps you can use a predefined delimiter such as a pipe | to separate the values? {times ability1 is used}|{times ability2 is used}|...|{times ability 8 is used}, or even {ability name 1}:{times ability1 is used}|{ability name 2}:{times ability2 is used}, etc.? You can then parse the data out in your ETL process or something